# QR Code scanning android

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing

I am using Zxing `Barcode scanner app` to scan bar codes using

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");

startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

It works fine. I could get the result in `onActivityResult`. No problem. I dont want QRCode to be displayed. I mean I don't want to let the end user know the `qr code string`. But in the history available in the original `barcode scanner app`, it is showing up the list of QR's scanned. So, how do i make the `QRString`from my app invisible in `History`

Comment: Does it supports android 2.2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**"SAVE_HISTORY"** from `package com.google.zxing.client.android.Scan;`

```
 /**
     * Setting this to false will not save scanned codes in the history.
     */
    public static final String SAVE_HISTORY = "SAVE_HISTORY";
```

Then something like,

```
intent.putExtra("SAVE_HISTORY", false);
```

Try this and let me know what happen..

Comment: Look a this [link](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android/src/com/google/zxing/client/android/Intents.java)

Comment: Seshu -- this answer is correct. Each of your comments is wrong or unhelpful. Yes you need to spend time and effort. This answer *is* sending extras by Intent. This extra *does* mean "don't save in history". It does work. The word is "false" and not "fals". Try sending Boolean.TRUE.

Comment: yea i have sent false. I mistyped it as fals yesterday. It worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: @SeanOwen  I want access those saved history, in my app do you know any solution such that we can access the history from our app? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19217993/how-to-call-scanned-barcode-history-from-zxing

Comment: No, this is not allowed for security. This is not the right place to ask a new question