# How to call scanned barcode history from zxing

Tags: android, zxing, barcode-scanner

I am scanning barcodes using Zxing in my application i have a button called History onclick it should display scanned barcode history i dont know how to call history from zxing.

Comment: It's not possible. This would be a big security hole to let anyone else ask for your scan history by Intent.

Comment: @minion  can u pls share how u done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by Zxing, you mean you are using the library (not the zxing client app) to scan QR codes then you will have to implement the history related functionality on your own. Basically save items in the database base each time you have successfully scanned something.

Take a look at the implementation of history feature in the sample zxing android client. https://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android/src/com/google/zxing/client/android/history/HistoryManager.java

Comment: can u discuss how further it can be done may i need to use this class ?